# react-hook-form: Validation not working when using onBlur mode

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, yup, react-hook-form

I am trying to display an error with `yup` and `react-hook-form` when the user selects more than 5 checkboxes without success.

Instead, the error is shown when the seventh checkbox is selected.

Here is the simplified code:

```
imports...

const schema = yup.object().shape({
  option: yup.array().max(5)
});
function App() {
  const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm({
    mode: "onBlur",
    resolver: yupResolver(schema)
  });

  const [state, setState] = useState({
    wasSubmitted: false
  });

  const submit = async (data) => {
    window.alert(JSON.stringify(data));
  };

  if (state.wasSubmitted) {
    return <p>Congrats</p>;
  } else {
    return (
      <>
        <CssBaseline />
        <Container maxWidth="sm">
          <Typography variant="h2" component="h1">
            My form
          </Typography>
          <form noValidate autoComplete="off" onSubmit={handleSubmit(submit)}>
            <FormControl
              component="fieldset"
              error={!!errors.option}
            >
              <FormLabel component="legend">
                Please select the category or categories of books the child is
                interested in:
              </FormLabel>
              <FormGroup>
                <FormControlLabel
                  control={<Checkbox name="option" inputRef={register} />}
                  value="Option1"
                  label="Option 1"
                />
                <FormControlLabel
                  control={<Checkbox name="option" inputRef={register} />}
                  value="Option2"
                  label="Option 2"
                />
                <FormControlLabel
                  control={<Checkbox name="option" inputRef={register} />}
                  label="Option3"
                  value="Option 3"
                />
                <FormControlLabel
                  control={<Checkbox name="option" inputRef={register} />}
                  value="Option4"
                  label="Option 4"
                />
                <FormControlLabel
                  control={<Checkbox name="option" inputRef={register} />}
                  value="Option5"
                  label="Option 5"
                />
                <FormControlLabel
                  control={<Checkbox name="option" inputRef={register} />}
                  value="Option6"
                  label="Option 6"
                />
                <FormControlLabel
                  control={<Checkbox name="option" inputRef={register} />}
                  value="Option7"
                  label="Option 7"
                />
                <FormControlLabel
                  control={<Checkbox name="option" inputRef={register} />}
                  value="Option8"
                  label="Option 8"
                />
                <FormControlLabel
              <FormHelperText>Up to five categories</FormHelperText>
            </FormControl>

            <Button
              type="submit"
              disableElevation
            >
              Submit
            </Button>
          </form>
        </Container>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

You can also find the project's sandbox here:

[image: Edit modern-resonance-d7mpc]

Any ideas?

Comment: Change mode of `useForm` to onChange: `useForm({ mode: "onChange", ...`

Comment: Thank you! that fixed the issue. Also, I just realized that, if you change mode of `useForm` to `useForm({ mode: "all"...`,  you get both behaviours `onChanage` and `onBlur`

Answer (score 41, accepted):

As @aadlc said, the solution is to set the mode to `onChange` or `all`. I'll explain the reason why.

From react-hook-form [API docs](https://react-hook-form.com/api):

`mode: onChange | onBlur | onSubmit | onTouched | all = 'onSubmit'`

| Name | Type | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| onSubmit (Default) | string | Validation will trigger on the `submit` event and invalid inputs will attach `onChange` event listeners to re-validate them. |
| onBlur | string | Validation will trigger on the `blur` event. |
|  |  |  |
| onChange | string | Validation will trigger on the `change` event with each input, and lead to multiple re-renders. Warning: this often comes with a significant impact on performance. |
|  |  |  |
| onTouched | string | Validation will trigger on the first `blur` event. After that, it will trigger on every `change` event. |
| all | string | Validation will trigger on the `blur` and `change` events. |

In your code, the form mode is `onBlur`. it means the validation is triggered on `blur` event (unfocus the input). When you select the option `n+1`, it triggers the blur event from the option `n`.

e.g. Just before you select the 6th option (invalid), the `blur` event fires from the 5th option (valid) because you're no longer focusing it, and validate from option 1-5, so you have to check the 7th option to revalidate the option from 1 to 6.

```
-- select up to 5 options --
select option 4

blur event fires from option 4 -> validate -> pass
select option 5

blur event fires from option 5 -> validate -> pass
select option 6

blur event fires from option 6 -> validate -> fail
select option 7
```

Changing the valiation mode to `onChange` will validate *after* `change` event is triggered, when all of the values are up-to-date:

```
-- select up to 5 options --
select option 4

blur event fires from option 4
select option 5
change event fires from option 5 -> validate -> pass

blur event fires from option 5
select option 6
change event fires from option 6 -> validate -> fail

blur event fires from option 6
select option 7
change event fires from option 7 -> validate -> fail
```

Changing the valiation mode to `all` will validate both in `blur` and `change` events, which may be overkill in this workflow, but it also works.

Comment: example: useForm({mode: 'onBlur'})

Comment: Saved my day! Took a couple hours looking for this configuration, appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 9):

If you're using controlled components onBlur might not be automatically firing. You will have to wire it manually:

[useController docs](https://react-hook-form.com/api/usecontroller)
[wrapper docs](https://react-hook-form.com/api/usecontroller/controller)

```
export const MyControlledField = ({ fieldName }: { fieldName: string }) => {
  const methods = useFormContext();
  const value = useWatch({ name: fieldName });
  const controller = useController({
    name: fieldName,
    control: methods.control,
  });
  return (
    <TextField
      value={value ?? ''}
      onChange={(e) => {
        methods.setValue(fieldName, e.target.value);
      }}
      onBlur={controller.field.onBlur}
    />
  );
};
```

Or using a wrapped component:

```
export const MyWrappedField = ({ fieldName }: { fieldName: string }) => {
  const methods = useFormContext();

  return (
    <Controller
      control={methods.control}
      name={fieldName}
      render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur, value, name, ref }, fieldState, formState }) => (
        <TextField
          onBlur={onBlur}
          onChange={onChange}
          value={value}
          inputRef={ref}
        />
      )}
    />
  );
};
```