# Validation at form level on multiple fields with Yup and react-hook-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yup, react-hook-form

I currently have the following Yup validation schema with react-hook-form:

```
  const schema = yup.object().shape({
    externallyPrintedLabelsQty: yup
      .number()
      .typeError("Number of Labels (printed outside) must be a number")
      .required()
      .integer()
      .min(0)
      .max(2)
      .test(
        "maxLabels",
        "A maximum of two labels per pack, either printed internally or externally, is allowed.",
        function (value: any) {
          const { internallyPrintedLabelsQty } = this.parent;
          return value + internallyPrintedLabelsQty < 3;
        }
      ),
    internallyPrintedLabelsQty: yup
      .number()
      .typeError("Number of Labels (printed inside) must be a number")
      .required()
      .integer()
      .min(0)
      .max(2),
  });
```

This works fine. However, the `.test` validation is attached to a specific field (i.e. `externallyPrintedLabelsQty`).
Is there any way to attach the `.test` to the form as a whole instead of to a specific field, or test whether at form level the user is selecting more than 2 labels, regardless if they are printed internally or externally?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.test` is also a method of `Yup.object`. That means that appending `.test` to your `ObjectSchema` will do the trick, like so:

```
const schema = yup
    .object()
    .shape({
        externallyPrintedLabelsQty: yup
            .number()
            .typeError('Number of Labels (printed outside) must be a number')
            .required()
            .integer()
            .min(0)
            .max(2),
        internallyPrintedLabelsQty: yup
            .number()
            .typeError('Number of Labels (printed inside) must be a number')
            .required()
            .integer()
            .min(0)
            .max(2),
    })
    .test(
        'maxLabels',
        'A maximum of two labels per pack, either printed internally or externally, is allowed.',
        (value) => {
            const externallyPrintedLabelsQty =
                value?.externallyPrintedLabelsQty ?? 0;
            const internallyPrintedLabelsQty =
                value?.internallyPrintedLabelsQty ?? 0;

            return externallyPrintedLabelsQty + internallyPrintedLabelsQty < 3;
        }
    );
```

Comment: This is definitely a correct answer. However, react-hook-form seems to run the full validation and display the error, only on submit and not when moving from field to field. Do you have any suggestions on how to run the .test and display the error on blur?

Comment: There is already a resolved question on SO with an example of what you might be looking for [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66758855/react-hook-form-validation-not-working-when-using-onblur-mode)